# Exporting FBX Files - One Action per FBX?

Tags: python, scripting, export

**Hello everyone!**

I am new at blender but i need to learn it for a job. I worked like 3 years on maya but I would like to add my maya workflow on blender...

My probleme is : I would like to export **each action of my scene as one fbx for each**. I could export them one by one but sometimes my work need to have around 40-50 different actions.

[image]

This is my goal, but acutally I did 1 by 1!

If I compare to maya I would like duplicate the game exporter who actually work well for my work
if someone know something similar on blender let me know or I would like to script it.

thanks you !